# Dialog has lot of blank spaces in API 19 and lower

Tags: java, android, dialog, blank-line

I have a problem with custom dialogs in API 19 and lower.

The problem is that when I set a dialog in lower level API's.
I get a lot of blank spaces between all my text and button lines.
Even though I haven't set any padding or layout margin in my code.

API level 20 and higher works smoothly (without blank spaces).

Does someone know how the problem can be solved?

Cheers!

Comment: Please post your code @Stan1623

Comment: I already solved it!

Thanks anyway!

Comment: It was caused by layoutparams.

Comment: @Stan1623, if you think your solution might be helpful to others, you can post it as an answer.